# ASP.NET Menu Parent Menu Item Highlighting on Hover when Flyouts are enabled

Tags: asp.net, javascript, css, menu, hover

I have a ASP.Net Menu Control with three levels and flyouts enabled.
I want to highlight the parent items (right upto the top level parent) whenever a user hovers over the menu items.

I do not want to use a client side solution as described here:
http://www.codeproject.com/KB/webforms/AspMenuParentHighlighting.aspx

Is there an elegant server side solution?

Kind regards.

Comment: I think a solution for this has to be a combination of client side and server side code. If your solution is 100% server side you will have way too many postbacks. Can you give some more detail on what you want to be on the server side?

Comment: Part of the solution would be client side.
...but I would want the control to emit the js for that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only server side solution I can think of would be to set the client side solution on page load.

Is there a reason that you would want to build this server side rather than client side? Because forcing an event like this to occur server side is, by definition, rather inelegant.

Comment: Thats the same thing I am trying to do.
...but the fact that the Menu Item of an asp:Menu does not inherit from control has made it difficult.
Any sugestions?